# Can I use a 50MHz external oscillator for an ESP32-D0WD-V3?

Tags: oscillator, external

Can I use a 50MHz external oscillator for an ESP32-D0WD-V3 instead of a 40MHz external oscillator?  I only have 50 MHz at hand.

Comment: Does the part on page 10 of [this datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf) where it says "External 2 MHz ~ 60 MHz crystal oscillator (40 MHz only for Wi-Fi/Bluetooth functionality)" help at all?

Comment: unfortunately I wanna use Wi-Fi/Bluetooth functionality. :( but thank you, now I know where to look exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ESP32 Technical Reference Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUlt4.png), the maximum external clock rate is 40MHz.

[image]